# Not receiving body when a request returns a error - Spring Boot Feign Client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, feign, openfeign

Techs:

- One module with Spring Boot 2.1.7 (starter web, openfeign)
- Api Gateway With Spring Boot 2.1.3

I wanna capture the error from the feign client to send again on my error message. But when I debug the response it shows nothing on the body. But, when I try to reproduce the same call on `Postman` the response comes with the body.

I would like to know how I can get the variable the message that is transmitted on Postman and why my request doesn't bring the same body response.

Log trace from feign client

[image]

Postman Request

[image]

Comment: Check this, maybe it will help: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/260

Comment: I haven't tested the solution above yet, but I could find the error content by using `new String(e.content())` on Exception Handler.

In my case, I used AspectJ as the Exception Handler for the Feign Client, But I believe it could be, also, with Feign Decoder or Spring Controller Advice.